# HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "Greeter" not found - this is the problem i'm getting [Hardhat, openzeppelin]

Tags: solidity, contract-development, openzeppelin, hardhat, binance-smart-chain

I keep getting this error when doing: npx hardhat run scripts/sample-script.js --network testnet. Edited the name of my computer for security reasons.

Compiling 10 files with 0.8.4
Compilation finished successfully
HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "Greeter" not found.

```
at Artifacts._handleWrongArtifactForContractName (/Users/secret/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:473:11)
at Artifacts._getArtifactPathFromFiles (/Users/secret/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:587:19)
at Artifacts._getArtifactPath (/Users/secret/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:270:17)
at Artifacts.readArtifact (/Users/secret/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:50:26)
at getContractFactoryByName (/Users/secret/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/helpers.ts:100:20)
at main (/Users/secret/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /scripts/sample-script.js:17:19)
```

secret@MacBook-Air-som-tillhor-secret Code 2 - Hardhat  %

This is the view of the situation. If there's a contract you want me to upload, just say it I will upload. Thankful for every help I get.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have named your contract 'Nikola' and not 'Greeter'. The actual file-names only matter for imports.

Comment: I changed the name of greeter.sol to nikola.sol but the problem remained, as I said before I'm very much thankful for your support, but would need a piece of extra advice on how I can fix this. There were two contracts, one Nikola and one greeter, and I deleted the greeter to then be able to fix it, but it didn't, same problem? Was I supposed to do that? Any advice on what I should do to fix it? Now I have tried it again and got this error: Error: Cannot find module '@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle'

Comment: the name of your contract is defined when you write `contract Nikola { ...` not by the .sol file